# Which is the best clustering algorithm to find outliers?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, outliers

Basically I have some hourly and daily data like

Day 1

Hours,Measure
(1,21)
(2,22)
(3,27)
(4,24)

Day 2
hours,measure
(1,23)
(2,26)
(3,29)
(4,20)

Now I want to find outliers in the data by considering hourly variations and as well as the daily variations using bivariate analysis...which includes hourly and measure...

So which is the best clustering algorithm is more suited to find outlier considering this scenario?
.

Comment: There really is no "best" way.  "So good advice here is: Beware of good advice about this." --Berton Gunter (replying to the question what the best way to detect an outlier is) R-help, Sept 2004

Answer (score 2):

one 'good' advice (:P) I can give you is that (based on my experience) it is NOT a good idea to treat time similar to spatial features. So beware of solutions that do this. You probably can start with searching the literature in outlier detection for time-series data.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use a different repesentation for your data.

Why don't you use an actual outlier detection method, if you want to detect outliers?

Other than that, just read through some literature. k-means for example is known to have problems with outliers. DBSCAN on the other hand is designed to be used on data with "Noise" (the N in DBSCAN), which essentially are outliers.

Still, the way you are representing your data will make none of these work very well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use time series based outlier detection method because of the nature of your data (it has its own seasonality, trend, autocorrelation etc.). Time series based outliers are of different kinds (AO, IO etc.) and it's kind of complicated but there are applications which make it easy to implement.

Download the latest build of R from http://cran.r-project.org/. Install the packages "forecast" & "TSA".

Use the auto.arima function of forecast package to derive the best model fit for your data amd pass on those variables along with your data to detectAO & detectIO of TSA functions. These functions will pop up any outlier which is present in the data with their time indexes.

R is also easy to integrate with other applications or just simply run a batch job ....Hope that helps...